# Java | Data Structures - Storing different object by a String

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, storage

I'm writing a plugin for Minecraft Bukkit, and I find that I am using a lot of HashMaps. I'm using player's UUID (as a String) to store their data, and what I have looks something like this:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> balances;
private static Map<String, String> nicknames;
private static Map<String, List<Achievements>> achievements;
private static Map<String, Rank> ranks;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    balances = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    nicknames = new HashMap<String, String>();
    achievements = new HashMap<String, List<Achievement>>();
    ranks = new HashMap<String, Rank>();
}
```

Don't worry, the question I am asking has nothing to do with Minecraft Bukkit, so you don't need to know anything about that. What I am asking, is if there is a better data structure that I can use? I feel like I'm using too many HashMaps.

Does anyone know a better alternative? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That depends entirely on how you interact with the data. If you mostly do lookups based on the key, then stick with `HashMap`s.

Comment: @resueman but the thing is, the key is the same for every hashmap, so I feel like I shouldn't be using it over and over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should create a User object.

```
class User {
    Integer balance;
    String nickname;
    List<Achievements> achievements;
    Rank rank;
}

private static Map<String, User> users;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `Player` class. Each `Player` instance can keep its own data. And you can keep all players in a hash map with using uuid as key.

```
public class Player {
     private String uuid;
     private int balance;
     private String nickName;

     //other fields
}
```

Comment: Then give it a different name

Answer (score 1):

You may want to store the values in a dedicated class:

```
public class PlayerInfo {
    private String userUUID;
    private int balance;
    // ...
}

Map<String, PlayerInfo> playerInfos = // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The form you are using is quite relevent. You can also create a subclass like:

```
public class PlayerData {
    public int balance;
    public String nickname;
    ...
}
```

Then use:

```
private static Map<String, PlayerData> balances;
```